# Insert PHP PDO via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm hittin' the wall for some days already, and can't seem to resolve this simple problem.

I want to make a simple insert via ajax. As i'm new to PHP, I've seen many examples, read the POST stuff for http and php, read te jquery.ajax documentation, and I'm aware of the PDO documentation aswell.
Still, can't find why it's not working.

Here goes the codes, really simple:

Index

```
<body>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="" >
        Nome:
        <input type="text" name="nome" required />
        <br/>
        Tipo:
        <input type="text" name="tipo" required />
        <br/>


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" id="sub"/> 


    </form>

    <script src="script/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/ajaxInclude.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "DAO/insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('ERRO');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Config :

```
<?php

define('HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME','test');
define('PORT', '3306');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.HOST.'; port='.PORT.'; dbname='.DB_NAME;

try {
$bd = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
//  $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATT_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Houve algum erro no Banco de Dados';
}

?>
```

Insert:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

    $sql =  'INSERT INTO produto(id, nome, tipo, criado_em) ';
    $sql .= ' VALUES (NULL, :nome, :tipo, NOW())';

    try {
        $query = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':tipo', $tipo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($query->execute()){
            echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
        }else{
            echo "Falha na inser��o de dados";
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

I've changed it a million times, and still, I can't even get the returns from the insert, I just get the alert from the sucess from ajax.

Sorry for so simple question, but I'm having some bad time with it. I'm trying to do all with the best practices I've found, and haven't found a solid example of this.

Comment: First of all you have to understand that there is **no such thing like "Insert PHP PDO via AJAX"**. It's either AJAX or PDO. they NEVER interfere. So, decide first, which realm your question belongs to

Comment: You should be seeing an error in your Javascript console. You're using `$_POST` in your Javascript, but that is a PHP superglobal. It does not exist in Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = $_POST['#myForm'].serialize();
```

should probably be

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
```

Additionally, you should check for all required parameteres if they're set, submit will never be set, because your submit-input doesn't have a `name` attribute:

```
if(isset($_POST['nome'], $_POST['tipo'])) {
    // your stuff here...
}
```

And leaving "php mode" in this way can result in blank lines and you have no idea where they come from later:

```
?>

<?php
```

Comment: Actually these php are separated files, I should have explained it better over here, sorry.
Gonna edit my quote

Comment: Same for single PHP files, you would usually leave out the closing tag ;)

Comment: Anyways, I've changed the serialize line, and the sucess from ajax is returning my whole php file. And I still don't get any return from the insert module.

Comment: @DaniloScanferla Probably, you forgot to change the `if` in your php file as well.

Comment: I've edited my code. I'm evaluating if(isset($_POST['submit'])), and I've named my Button, as @user574632 told below. Doesn't it work aswell ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` on top of your php file print?

Comment: The var_dump doesn't prints anything.
I just get the error message from ajax now

Comment: Then it doesn't get executed. It should at least print `array(0){}`

Comment: i'm changind a lot of stuff randomly here to see if the changes make anything. When it goes to the "success" from ajax, I still gets the whole php file on alert, but the var_dumps don't returns me anything.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "the whole php file"?

Comment: It returns me the insert file, from <?php to ?>, all of it as text

Comment: Then your file doesn't get executed. If you use apache, try to add something like `AddType text/html .php` to your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2):

1st as mentioned by Kelunik you have php mixed in with your javascript:

```
var data = $_POST['#myForm'].serialize();
```

`$_POST` is a php array. This should be:

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
```

Second (and the reason you see an empty alert), you dont have a name attribute on your submit button, so the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` conditional check in php fails.
Change:

```
<input type="submit" value="save" id="sub"/>
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" id="sub"/>
```

Lastly, if this php file produces other output (as your comments suggest) make sure you stop execution after returning your responce:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //your sql code and responces here
    //then stop script
    die();
}
```

Comment: Actually the output from php file are just the echoes I put on the query->execute. I should get a "Data inserted successfully" or "DataBase error" on that. But i'm getting the succes output from ajax only, and even that doesn't make sense because i'm getting the whole php file

Comment: @DaniloScanferla So php isnt being processed?? have you tried running a simple php script on your server?

Comment: Yeap, you just killed it.
Sorry for the n00b mistake, but there was something wrong with the server. I have changed it and now it's working perfectly :)

Thanks a lot user574632 and @kelunik